# error PHP-LARAVEL Undefined variable: calificacions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mvc

Estoy realizando este proyecto en Laravel, pero me aparece este error:

`Undefined variable $calificacions (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\AistemaAlumnos8\resources\views\Calificaciones\editar.blade.php)`

**En mi controller tengo esto "CalificacionController.php"**
[image: CalificacionController]
[image: parte 2 CalificacionController]

**y en mi edit view blade tengo esto: "editar.blade.php"**

[image: edit view parte 1]
[image: edit view parte 2]
[image: edit view parte 3]

Tengo que entregarlo para el 21 de Abril ya que es proyecto final, me serviria de ayuda que ayudaran en esto. Gracias!!!!!

Comment: Hola April, bienvenida, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No estas proporcionando al view de la función `edit` el objeto `calificacion` debería ser algo así:

```
$calificacions = Calificacion::find($id);
```

y esta misma var `$calificacions` pasarsela a tu view

```
return view('Calificaciones.editar', array('permission' => $permission, 'calificacions' => $calificacions));
```

Comment: Aun asi me sale ese mismo error de undefined variable

Comment: Aun así no arreglas tu pregunta como debe ser. Terminara cerrada !!!

Answer (score 0):

El error puede estar en el nombre de las variables, estás pasando a tu plantilla de `Blade` la variable `calificaciones` y en tu plantilla estás leyendo otra diferente llamada `calificacions`, puede ser un error semántico, cambia al pasar tu variable `calificaciones` a tu plantilla:

```
return view('Calificaciones.index', array('calificacions' => $calificaciones));
```

O cambia el acceso a tu variable `calificaciones` en tu plantilla de `Blade`:

```
{{!! Form::model($calificaciones, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['Calificaciones.update', $calificaciones->id]]) !!}}
```